# Fourier Series on [-L , L].

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Prove that the Fourier transform of an integrable function f satisfies:

(i) $\hat{f}$ is bounded.

Where the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of an integrable function $f$ is defined as the sequence $(c_{n}(f))_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}.$
Where $c_{n}(f)$ is the Fourier coefficients of a function $f \in L^{1}([-L,L])$, and is defined to be $$c_{n}(f) = \frac{1}{2L}\int^{L}_{-L} f(x) \overline{g_{n}(x)}dx = \langle f,g_{n}\rangle.$$
And for $L>0$ and for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we take $$g_{n}(x) = e^{in\pi x/L}. $$

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your $f$ is in $L^1[-L,L]$ by assumption, the result should be obvious, once you notice that
$$ \left| \int_{-L}^L fg_n \right| \leq \int_{-L}^L |fg_n | = \int_{-L}^L |f |.$$

(Though usually Fourier series are defined for functions in $L^2[-L,L]$, where the $\langle . , . \rangle$ you wrote down is the natural inner product. In this case, you could use Bessel's inequality or Parseval's theorem.)

Comment: But what if $f(x) = \frac{sin x}{x} $ in this case $\int_{0}^{\infty} |\frac{sin x}{x}| dt = +\infty$, so how is the Fourier transform bounded in this case?

Comment: What is Parseval`s theorem ?

Comment: @weakmathematician If $f(x) = \sin x / x$, then the Fourier transform is the top-hat function. (See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) So the Fourier transform _is_ bounded. (Anyway, your question was really about Fourier SERIES, so this doesn't apply.)

Comment: Parseval's theorem is the statement that if $g_n$ is a complete orthonormal set in a Hilbert space (such as your $g_n = e^{2\pi inx / L}$ in the Hilbert space $L^2([-L,L])$, then $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty |\langle f, g_n \rangle |^2 = |f|^2_{L^2}$. See here for the general Hilbert space version:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality and see here for the Fourier series version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem

Comment: My question was about Fourier series?

Comment: Yes it was. You wrote "Fourier transform" in your post, but your question was actually about Fourier series. When you evaluate $c_n = \langle f, g_n \rangle$ with $g_n = e^{2\pi i n / L}$,  you are actually evaluating the coefficients of the Fourier SERIES of $f$. (In other words, these coefficients $c_n$ satisfy the nice property that $f = \sum_n c_n g_n$.)

Comment: So, your answer is wrong in our case?

Comment: In which case, sorry?

Comment: I mean your answer for the question that I post, is it still right? I only got confused.

Comment: Yes, I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: so  the Fourier transfom is bounded for the function I mentioned?  ...... why u wrote "so this doesn't apply"?

Comment: Yes, in fact the Fourier transform is $ \chi_{[-1,1]}$, where $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ takes values of $1$ on $[-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. (I may have got some constant factors wrong, so please check...)

Comment: why you wrote "(Anyway, your question was really about Fourier SERIES, so this doesn't apply.)"

Comment: Because my "official" answer to your "official" question was about Fourier series. However, you are now asking about the Fourier TRANSFORM of $\sin x / x$, and what I gave you was the Fourier transform, which is indeed bounded.

Comment: To argue that $f \in L^1(\mathbb R) $ implies that the Fourier transform $\hat f$ is bounded is very straightforward. The point is that $| \hat f (\omega) | \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x) | |e^{i\omega x}| dx = || f ||_{L^1}$, so the Fourier transform is bounded by the $L^1$ norm of the original function. It is a very similar argument to the one I gave about Fourier series in my "official" answer.

Comment: I have seen the following link that you mentioned above https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function  but it does not convince me that the Fourier transform is bounded because I have mentioned to you that $\int_{0}^{\infty} | \frac{sin t}{t}|dt = +\infty $ this function inside the integral sign not the result of the integration.

Comment: you know $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin t}{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$, it is different from the integration over the absolute value of $(sin t)/ t$

Comment: @weakmathematician I didn'y notice that! Then the conclusion is that $\sin t / t$ is not in $L^1$! (Apparently you can extend the definition of Fourier transforms to functions not in $L^1$ using the theory of distributions, but i don't know much about that...) Anyway, once you've decided that the Rectangular function is the Fourier transform, then the Fourier transform is bounded simply because the rectangular function is bounded.